# Will iOS allow alerts from a bluetooth peripheral?

Tags: ios, bluetooth

Is it possible to have a bluetooth peripheral, a big red button for example, to cause an alert on a iOS? More specifically:

- the bluetooth device has been paired
- there is an app running on the phone that has communication with the peripheral
- the phone is locked or the app is backgrounded

If the red button is pressed, will the iOS accept the data and cause an alert to appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can post a local notification from an app in the background in response to Bluetooth data.  The simplest way is to use a Bluetooth Low Energy peripheral.  If you use Bluetooth 2.1 then you will need to go through the MFi program.

I have an example project here - https://github.com/paulw11/BeanLock that scans for a LightBlue Bean in the background and displays an alert when a successful connection is made.  Changing the code to issue the alert when an attribute changes (linked to a button) rather than simply on connection would be easy.